# TypeError: a float is required in time.sleep()

Tags: python, python-2.7, time, floating-point, sleep

In the beginning of my script, I call some info from a file, as you can see here:

```
with open('main.txt') as main:
    for line in main:
        secondary, delay = line.split(':')
```

Then something happens, and at the and of the loop I want it to sleep.
So I have this piece of code:

```
print "Delay entered until next cluster:",
print delay.rstrip("\n"),
print "seconds\n"
delay = delay.rstrip('\n')
time.sleep(delay)
```

Everything works absolutely fine!
Except for that last part, every time I run it, it gives me the following error:

```
    time.sleep(delay)
TypeError: a float is required
```

I've searched around a bit and found a similar call for help where someone replied he had to try:
x = float(x)

So that's why I've tried:

```
delay = delay.rstrip('\n')
time.sleep(delay)
```

And still no luck.

I'm sure this is some easy fix, and I've been overlooking the answer for the past hour, but this is driving me insane!
It went from fun to challenging and now it's becoming absolutely frustrating!

Comment: So, uh... your code doesn't call `float`. Why not?

Answer (score 5):

`sleep()` needs a float and you're giving it a string. You need an explicit conversion:

```
time.sleep(float(delay))
```

Comment: Shoot me.
That was all that was needed, you have no idea how I feel right now, after realizing I was this stupid. I thank you a lot